# IIS7.5 Windows Authentication missing providers menu item (ntlm)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, ntlm

I'm trying to enable NTLM authentication on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with IIS 7.5 for a specific file in my web root. I've been following these instructions http://docs.moodle.org/en/NTLM_authentication#IIS_Configuration

In the IIS Manager I open the Authentication module, disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication however according to every post I can find on the matter I should have a 'providers' option appear but I don't.

I've double checked in Server Manager that the 'Windows Authentication' security feature is enabled for IIS.

Any help anyone can offer would be great,

Thank you!

Comment: Are you attempting this EXACTLY like it says in the screenshot? I hate to be redundant, but I just installed a brand new IIS 7.5 on a VM, and the option is there.

Comment: and also, I hate to do it, but are you 100% positive you're running 2008R2? In Server 2008 (iis 7) there is no user interface for this functionality.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, although my server is an AWS Datacenter 2008R2. (Although the version says Build 7601: Service Pack 1. Is that right?)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, after verification with other servers where i see this option I found out it's missing on Windows Server 2008. Whereas on Server 2008 R2 this option is available.

Regards,
Przemek

Answer (score 0):

When you enable Windows Authentication (and you have it selected), an option should appear on the right: http://d.pr/Zng5

You can also right-click and get the option as well.

Dan

Comment: That's the thing though, the Provider's option isn't there. I would try re-installing the Windows Authentication feature however the checkbox is disabled despite me being the administrator...

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I get http://twitpic.com/48ahme/full

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can't specify providers for an individual page? (that's what the screenshot's showing you trying to do).

First, try it at the Server or Site level; if they work, work your way down.

Comment: Page, Folder, or Site. It works on all levels.